# How to fix NoReverseMatch?

Tags: python, forms, django-views

I want to back to the current page, when I click the submit.

No matter whether I redirected, still report `NoReverseMatch` ,as long as I click submit, but database has been added.

**urls.py**

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('student/', include('student.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

**app.urls.py**

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    app_name = 'student'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

    from .forms import StudentForm
    from .models import Student

    def index(request):
        students = Student.get_all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = StudentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                #return redirect(reverse('index'))
        else
            form = StudentForm()

        context = {'students': students, 'form':form,}

        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

**index.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>学员管理系统</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3><a href="/admin/">管理员</a></h3>
            <ul>
                {% for student in students %}
                <li>{{ student.name }} - {{ student.get_status_display 
    }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <hr/>
            <form  method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[the page like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAloj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe did you forget to add your app to the INSTALLED_APPS list in the settings.py file?

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'student.apps.StudentConfig'`
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct if the app name is 'student', try printing the result of the function reverse('index') and see what's the output